# dplyr::coalesce throws error when column name is missing

Tags: r, dplyr

```
zed <- zed %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Email = coalesce(`Email Address`, Email, `E-mail Address`, `E-MAIL`, email, `E-Mail`, `E-mail`, `E-Mail Address`, `EMAIL ADDRESS`, EMAIL))

Error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` column `Email`.
ℹ `Email = coalesce(...)`.
✖ object 'E-mail Address' not found
Caused by error in `list2()`:
! object 'E-mail Address' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How can we handle using `coalesce` to consolidate all of these columns into one column, while also handling the potential for one or more of these columns to be missing. Simply removing `E-mail Address` is not great because in other scenarios used by our function, `E-mail Address` will in fact exist.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `do.call` -

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- c("Email Address", "Email", "E-mail Address", "E-MAIL", "email")
# Sample data
set.seed(12442)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:10, NA), 25, replace = TRUE), 5, 5, 
                  dimnames = list(NULL, cols)), check.names = FALSE)
```

```
dat %>%
  mutate(Email_new = do.call(coalesce, pick(any_of(cols))))

#  Email Address Email E-mail Address E-MAIL email Email_new
#1             7     7              8      4    10         7
#2             7     7              4      1     3         7
#3             2     7             NA      3     9         2
#4            NA     4              6      9     9         4
#5             6     6              1     10     8         6
```

Now let's delete one of the column and try again with the same code.

```
dat$email <- NULL

dat %>%
   mutate(Email_new = do.call(coalesce, pick(any_of(cols))))

#  Email Address Email E-mail Address E-MAIL Email_new
#1             7     7              8      4         7
#2             7     7              4      1         7
#3             2     7             NA      3         2
#4            NA     4              6      9         4
#5             6     6              1     10         6
```

Comment: makes sense, clean and simple enough